# How to set the time stamp of the data frame to thw first day of the month

Tags: python, pandas, database, dataframe, resampling

I have a few data frames that i am resampling to match each other. I would like to set the **timestamps** (**index**) for all the data to be the first days of the month of the dsy the measurements were taken. I cannot find anywhere how to do it, the closest I got was with the resample(period=...), but it leaves me without the day.
The code I tried

```
df['value'].resample('M',kind = 'period').sum()
```

[image]

It comes like like this whereas I would like the timestamp to have the form of 2018-09-01.

Answer (score 2):

This line is all what you need:

```
df.index = pd.to_datetime(df.index).strftime('%Y-%m-%d')

# Output
#             value
# 2018-09-01     11
# 2018-10-01     12
```

It transforms your index column to a datetime type column. The first day of the month is automatically inserted. For more details, see the [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.22/generated/pandas.to_datetime.html#pandas-to-datetime).

Comment: I still get the time stamp as the last day of the month.. I treid using format =  '%01/%m/%Y', but doesnt work either..

Comment: Strange, it works for me. I modified the answer, forcing the date format. Could you please try again?

Comment: still all of them either -30th day or 31st... is there a way to force the number of the day to be "1"?

Comment: I am not sure why you get the last day of the month as default. If you want to force it, just use `df.index = df.index.strftime('%Y-%m') + '-01'`